# How to solve, PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.from'

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I'm following a tutorial on training data for a chatbot in python. However, whenever I run the code I get this error,

```
line 22, in <module>
    with open('test.from','a', encoding='utf8') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.from'
```

I went to my project folder and changed the permissions for 'staff' and 'everyone'. I made it so that both could read and write. However this did nothing, and I still got the same error.

Below is my code,

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

timeframes = ['2015-01']

for timeframe in timeframes:
    connection = sqlite3.connect('/Users/usr/Desktop/fileName/RC_{}.db'.format(timeframe))
    c = connection.cursor()
    limit = 5000
    last_unix = 0
    cur_length = limit
    counter = 0
    test_done = False

    while cur_length == limit:
        df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM parent_reply WHERE unix > {} and parent NOT NULL and score > 0 ORDER BY unix ASC LIMIT {}".format(last_unix,limit),connection)
        last_unix = df.tail(1)['unix'].values[0]
        cur_length = len(df)

        if not test_done:
            with open('test.from','a', encoding='utf8') as f:
                for content in df['parent'].values:
                    f.write(content+'\n')
            with open('test.to','a', encoding='utf8') as f:
                for content in df['comment'].values:
                    f.write(str(content)+'\n')
            test_done = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POssible reasons

1. The user does not have write access in that directory.
2. The file is write protected.
3. The file is in use at another source.

Most probably you dont have write access in that directory so put full path of a directory you have access to and try again.

Comment: I added the full path to the test.from & the test.to and it worked! Thanks!